# Receiving messages from another process

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi

It seems like I am missing something fundamental, from my application, upgraded from VB6. All I want to do, is for it to receive *SendMessage* messages from **another application**.

The older VB6 application works, however, I found that in the .Net world, overriding the *WndProc(ref Message m)* method doesn't work. Note, I do see messages, coming from withing the same application, e.g. if I move the mouse inside the window.

I tried mimicking what the VB6 did, i.e. using the *SetWindowLong* , *CallWindowProc*, etc... and doesn't work either.

I have sparsely read about DLL injecting ([P/Invoking SetWindowLong and CallWindowProc in managed code (compact framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104667/p-invoking-setwindowlong-and-callwindowproc-in-managed-code-compact-framework)) but can't seem to move forward on it.

Is this actually possible in .Net? I would hope someone can point me to the right direction.

**UPDATE:** There is a topic in MSDN about this. Here is the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-data-copy

But this is in C++. I'm wondering if this is possible in .NET

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsAppMessage
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //HandleCreated += Form1_HandleCreated;
    }


    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m.ToString());

        // Listen for operating system messages or from other applications
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

/*
    private void Form1_HandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _handle = this.Handle;
        Attach();
    }


    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int CallWindowProc(IntPtr lpPrevWndFunc, IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    private delegate int WindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    private const int GWL_WNDPROC = -4;

    private IntPtr _handle;
    private IntPtr _oldCallback;
    private WindowProc _newCallback;


    public void Attach()
    {
        _newCallback = WndProc; // Pins WndProc - will not be garbage collected.
        _oldCallback = SetWindowLong(_handle, GWL_WNDPROC,
            Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(_newCallback));

        // Just to be sure...
        if (_oldCallback == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }

    public void Detach()
    {
        if (_newCallback == null || _oldCallback == null)
            return;

        SetWindowLong(_handle, GWL_WNDPROC, _oldCallback);
        _newCallback = null;
    }

    private int WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(Msg.ToString());

        // Forward the message to the original WndProc function.
        return CallWindowProc(_oldCallback, hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

}
*/

}
```

Comment: I generally prefer to use `Debug.WriteLine` over `Console.WriteLine`, as it goes into the VS output window.  If you aren't running your application from a console, you won't see the console output.  That might be your issue; other than this, your code looks fine to me.  I've seen the `base.WndProc(ref m);` call at the top of the method, but I dont think that matters.

Comment: So what's the actual issue, you are not receiving messages, overriding WndProc doesn't work; DLL injection doesn't work,  please give an update what specifically isn't working so we can better assist. Currently it can be a number of things according to your current code, it's hard to tell at this point.

Comment: Are you certain you are sending the messages to the proper handle? How does your _other application_ determine Form1's handle?

Comment: In the .NET world, inter-process communication is more commonly going through other channels (pipe, socket and so on). If your goal is to rewrite a pretty old application, can you consider applying some modern technologies?

Comment: The "other application" and the "old VB6 app" still works. The "other application", unchanged, finds the VB6 app, and this "new" app by using the windows FindWindow API, and that works too (i.e. window handle is found). What doesn't work is that in the new App, it doesn't receive the messages from the other process/app.

Comment: Newer technologies (i.e. Memory-mapped files) are on this upgraded app. However, the business case demands to retain old compatibility.

Comment: The base.WndProc(ref m) call matters, as you have to pass on the message which other handlers may need (chaining).

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, I solved this issue. The main thing that I lacked, was programmatically enabling the messages from the "other app" from getting thru.

The topic to search is  User Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI), hence the need to explictly call *[ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changewindowmessagefilterex)* API.

For example:

```
 ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx(this.Handle, Constants.WM_COPYDATA, ChangeWindowMessageFilterExAction.Allow, ref filterStatus);
```